# Proximity alert android

Tags: android, locationmanager, proximity

I use proximity alert in my project, bu I don't understand it.

When I create new proximity alert with radius from my point, it will notifi when user is near this point.

I think about accuracy, what about very slow accuracy?

I saw alert notifi user when accuracy is bad, so distance is 2km instead 200 meters.

Any sugestion about this?